# Show that $\{\emptyset, \mathbb R\}\cup \{(-\infty, x): x\in \mathbb R\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, real-numbers

Show that $\{\emptyset, \mathbb R\}\cup \{(-\infty, x): x\in \mathbb R\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb R$.

i) Clearly the empty set and $\mathbb R$ are open by construction.

ii) Let $\{(-\infty, x_\alpha) \}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of intervals in $\mathbb R$. If the sequence $\{x_\alpha\}$ is bounded above, then $$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} (-\infty, x_\alpha)=(-\infty, \sup_{\alpha \in A} \{x_\alpha\} )$$ which is clearly open. Otherwise, the sequence is not bounded above then the union must converge to $\mathbb R$.

iii) Take the same family of sets from (ii) except assume the index set $A$ is finite. Then the sequence $\{x_\alpha\}$ clearly is bounded below, so we have $$\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} (-\infty, x_\alpha)=(-\infty, \inf_{\alpha \in A} \{x_\alpha\})$$ which is clearly open.

Does this cover all the bases for establishing a topology?

Comment: The empty set is not in your "topology". The first part should be $\{\emptyset, \Bbb R\}$, no $\{\{\emptyset\}, \Bbb R\}$

Comment: Yes. $\{\emptyset\}$ is a Singleton set , not empty.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I will fix that extra bracket error.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking you need to prove that the union of a family of open sets is also an open set. So you'll need to check (although is trivial) what happens when the family includes $\Bbb R$ or $\emptyset$. Same thing for the finite intersections.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes indeed, I thought of that, however if the union includes $\mathbb R$ then the entire union is of course $\mathbb R$, and if it includes $\emptyset$ then the union is the same as not including it, so it can be excluded without loss of generality. I guess it doesn't hurt to state these things for sake of precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is any arbitrary index set, hence $\{x_\alpha\}$ need not be a sequence ( a sequence is an enumeration of elements of a countable set) , it's an arbitrary subset of $\Bbb{R}$ .

The collection of subsets should be closed under arbitrary union.

If $\{x_\alpha :\alpha\in A\}$ is bounded above then it has a supremum in $\Bbb{R}$ and it will be the right end point of the interval of the
$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} (-\infty, x_\alpha)$

And if the set $\{x_\alpha :\alpha\in A\}$ is not bounded above then the union is $(-\infty, \infty)=\Bbb{R}$.

For the case of intersection, it is enough to take intersection of two members ( because of Induction !) . Again for the finite intersection , you always get minimum ( $\inf$ is also fine but $\min$ is more accurate)

Rest of the proof looks fine to me.

Comment: My understanding of your answer is it is different from what I wrote in that I should not have necessarily called $\{x_\alpha\}$ a "sequence" and also that using infimum was superfluous. Is that an accurate recapitulation?

Comment: Exactly.Except that your proof looks fine to me. Sequence is used to denote members of a countable set.